# ReplaceAll не заменяет пустые строки

Tags: java, input

Есть массив значений, который нужно отформатировать в одну строку для последующего удобного считывания программы.

---

Код:

---

```
static void tackOverfloyUpdate() {
    String input_data = "9711733 -2964269\r\n" + "18295 940\r\n" + "3582804 779\r\n" + "3062292 -3771370\r\n"
    + "5751495 754\r\n" + "8273943 899\r\n" + "-8009912 -386173\r\n" + "3978561 696\r\n" + "14319 1740\r\n"
    + "5180694 4278254\r\n" + "-5008179 4134120\r\n" + "7475 1692\r\n" + "4441598 94\r\n" + "16989 1596\r\n"
    + "17369 840\r\n" + "4311 532\r\n" + "-1461444 -3175361";
    // Здесь применяется ReplaceAll
    input_data = input_data.replaceAll("\n\r", " ");
    System.out.println("Все данные в одной строке: \n" + input_data);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    tackOverfloyUpdate();
}
```

---

После выполнения кода, текст остается таким же.

---

Comment: imput_data = imput_data.replace("\r\n", " ");

Comment: Оффтоп: i**n**put

Comment: Только что увидел что с моим кодом не так, как написал Serodv нужно было регулярки местами поменять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод replace возвращает **новую** строку, не изменяя старую, поэтому необходимо присваивание:
`imput_data = imput_data.replace(..., ...);`

[image: Работает же, результат внизу на черном фоне]

Comment: Не работает, исправил в коде, отображается так же как и в описании

Comment: @АйзекАзимов добавила скриншот с работоспособностью

Comment: its magic, делал тоже самое, не работало. Благодарю